# How to open AS400 emulator using Vbscript

Tags: vbscript, ibm-midrange, hta

I made a HTA app that needs to open As400 emulator but I can't make it work. This is my code.

```
Sub TestSub()       
    Dim sessName,sessNo,userName,pass,filePath,i,aw

    sessName = document.getElementById("session").value
    sessNo = document.getElementById("sessno").value
    userName = document.getElementById("uname").value
    pass = document.getElementById("psw").value
    sessName = sessName&".WS"
    filePath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private\"&sessName&".ws"       

    'sessNo = sessNo*1      
    'For i = 0 to sessNo            
        Set autECLConnMgr = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnMgr")
        Set autECLConnList = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLConnList")
        Set autECLOIA = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLOIA")
        Set autECLPS = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")   
        Set autECLSession = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLSession")     

            autECLConnList.Refresh()                        
            autECLConnMgr.StartConnection("PROFILE=filePath CONNNAME=A WINSTATE=RESTORE")
            autECLOIA.SetConnectionByName("A")
            autECLPS.SetConnectionByName("A")
            autECLOIA.WaitForAppAvailable()
            autECLOIA.WaitForInputReady()
    'Next 


    msgbox "Macro Finished!"
End Sub
```

I can't even open the emulator. Don't know what's wrong with my code since I'm just a beginner in making HTA apps. Thanks in advance!!

This is the error i get everytime I run it.

[image]

Comment: you are appending `ws` at two places, `sessName = sessName&".WS"` and `filePath = "C:\Users\Public\Documents\IBM\Client Access\Emulator\Private\"&sessName&".ws"` , so you will end up with an extension of `.WS.ws` in the `filePath`. Is that what you wanted?

Comment: And the value of the `filePath` should be concatenated like: ` autECLConnMgr.StartConnection("PROFILE="&filePath&" CONNNAME=A WINSTATE=RESTORE")`